# Good to use requirejs OR grunt with concat/minification for angularjs performance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, gruntjs

I have a doubt, In my angular app, I have so many js files, so when I load the app, all the .js files which is included in index.html file

```
<html>
...
<script src="scripts/controllers/loginController.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/explainedController.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/homeController.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/menuController.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/listController.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/treeController.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/jqueryController.js"></script
..
</html>
```

will be downloaded and then the app is ready. That's good so far, but for performance reasons I thought would be good if I use grunt task for concat and minification using

```
grunt-contrib-concat, grunt-contrib-uglify
```

So after minification I ended up with only one file. So now my index file looks like:

```
<html>
...
<!--script src="scripts/controllers/loginController.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/explainedController.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/homeController.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/menuController.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/listController.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/treeController.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/jqueryController.js"></script-->
        <script src="scripts/production.min.js"></script> <!--Minified file -->
...
</html>
```

By this I have reduced the http calls to only one.

If this is good progress, Then adapting to require.js will get me even good progress/performance  or http call.. I do not think so.

OverAll , My question is:
For Better Performance of an angular App, Is it good to use grunt task like minification and compression Or good to use requirejs

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, the main benefit of requirejs is the **Dependencies Management**, i.e. which file should get executed before others. In Production, we usually ended up concat/minify with r.js to a single or a few files anyway, so the asynchronous loading feature isn't that useful.

Angular.js have its own **Dependency Injection** (DI) system and if you could put everything into the system correctly, you can arrange script tags in any order given that the module declaration `angular.module('app', ['blabla'])` run first. Therefore, this PARTLY solve the same dependencies management problem as requirejs do.

**Here is my advice**:

For a small to medium web application, if possible, stick with the plain script tags and use a build system such as grunt to concat/minify the code like you already do. Also see the [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) project.

For a large web application, it depends, there are things to consider if the `requirejs` is worth an effort to implement for the project:

- There are some old codebase that cannot be convert and put into the DI easily.
- Majority of developers aren't comfortable to write all the things in angular pattern, and they are familiar with requirejs already.
- The scripts lazy-downloading is required, but $script.js, Head.js can also be used instead
- There might be a lot of junk files that no one used it anymore but you're not sure if those files can completely removed or not, requirejs can help here in this scenario.
- There may be other scenarios, you have to do some research and evaluate if the `requirejs` should be used or not.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to use both.

As you already noticed, minification is good for performance, but I also like using require to structure my code one JS Module per file. This helps me to organize and navigate through the source code during the development process.

When I need to use a module in my Angular service, I just

```
var myModule = require('MyModule');
```

but if in development process it would turn out I don't need to use this module in my service anymore, I just remove the line above and MyModule.js is never loaded **unless** some other module *requires* it.

RequireJS relieves you of caring about the order of loading .js files. This problem also doesn't apply if you minify the whole source code to one file, but for debug purposes I usually don't use minified code during the development.

In a recent project I've had 31 js files stored in 6 folders + third party libraries. Without requirejs or some other AMD tool it would be a real pain to manage loading this.

If you're testing your Angular project with Karma, you have requirejs support out of the box.

Finally, require JS offers a minification/optimization tool:

http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html

which is able to recognize all the *requires* in your code and compile them into one file for you to load.